# Roblox Studio: "Argument 1 missing or nil"

Tags: roblox

I was testing out my script that finds the saved data. It gave me an error message saying "Argument 1 missing or nil".
Here's the code:

```lua
local DataStoreService = game:GetService("DataStoreService") -- makes the variable for the data store service

local DataStore = DataStoreService:GetDataStore("Data") -- makes the variable for the "Data" data store

local GlobalShutdowns = DataStore:GetAsync(GlobalShutdownsData) -- finds the "GlobalShutdownsData" data from the data store service
```

Please help me!

Comment: Could you please format your code using markdown?

Comment: how do you do that?

Comment: Three backticks. After that you type the language's name. So: \`\`\`lua (code in between) \`\`\`

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add quotes when calling `GetAsync`. This makes Luau believe that `GlobalShutdownsData` is a variable. `GlobalShutdownsData` is not defined (there is no variable named `GlobalShutdownsData`), therefore, the value is `nil`. Argument 1 of `GetAsync` is `nil`.

```lua
local DataStoreService = game:GetService("DataStoreService") -- makes the variable for the data store service

local DataStore = DataStoreService:GetDataStore("Data") -- makes the variable for the "Data" data store

--fix below
local GlobalShutdowns = DataStore:GetAsync("GlobalShutdownsData") -- finds the "GlobalShutdownsData" data from the data store service
```